# How to Join multiple records from the same two tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a question regarding joining multiple data from the same two tables.

The first table is called `imagedata` and it contains the following columns:

```
ID|image_blob|mimetype|image_UUID
```

the second table is called `price_history` and it contains the following columns:

```
price1|price2|image_name_homePage|image_name_loginPage|image_name_footer
```

What I am trying to pull is the `image_blob` from the `imagedata` table 
where

```
imagedata.ID=price_history.image_name_homePage
```

and where

```
imagedata.ID=price_history.image_name_loginPage
```

and where

```
imagedata.ID=price_history.image_name_footer
```

basically, what i am trying to achieve is a result that would show all the image blob from the `imagedata` where `imagedata.id` is equal to `price_history."price_history.image_*"`
I cannot seem to get it right. I get an empty result.
Here is my current Query:

```
SELECT 
    imagedata.`image_blob` as "blobA",
    imagedata.`image_blob` as "blobB",
    imagedata.`image_blob` as "blobC",
FROM 
    imagedata
    JOIN price_history AS price_historyA ON imagedata.`ID`=price_historyA.`image_name_homePage`
    JOIN price_history AS price_historyB ON imagedata.`ID`=price_historyB.`image_name_loginPage`
    JOIN price_history AS price_historyC ON imagedata.`ID`=price_historyB.`image_name_footer`
```

Comment: Can you show sample data and the expected result, or better provide an sqlfiddle.

Comment: The JOIN for `price_historyC` refers to `price_historyB` which may be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is close but you need to join `imagedata` table multiple times something as below, note that its using `left join` instead of inner join so that if some image value is missing on `price_history` you still get result with the other available images. If your DB is such that it will always have data for all all the images on `price_history` and corresponding items will be in the `imagedata` then you can just use `join` instead of `left join`

```
select
img1.image_blob as blobA,
img2.image_blob as blobB,
img3.image_blob as blobC,
from price_history ph
left join imagedata img1 on img1.id = ph.image_name_homePage
left join imagedata img2 on img2.id = ph.image_name_loginPage
left join imagedata img3 on img3.id = ph.image_name_footer
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the it! if I want to add more data from a third table `products` such as `product_name` and `product_updated`, can i join that as well? products has `prouductID` which equals to `prouductID` in `price_history`

Comment: I have uploaded a couple of screenshots to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
SELECT 
    imagedata.`ID`,
    imagedata.`image_blob` 
FROM 
    imagedata
JOIN price_history AS price_historyA ON imagedata.`ID`=price_historyA.`image_name_homePage`
AND imagedata.`ID`=price_historyA.`image_name_loginPage` 
AND imagedata.`ID`=price_historyA.`image_name_footer`
```

If what you want is that all three columns are equal to `imagedata.ID`

I am uploading screenshots to show the problem:
[image]
[image]